# Self-leveling concrete basement floor for tile installation

Tags: self-leveling-concrete

I’m renovating my basement and I’m stuck with a floor-leveling dilemma. The area in question is a half bath, which is about 6’ x 6’. The bathroom is in a corner of the basement.

Right now the bathroom has cheap laminate over the original poured concrete floor, which I’m planning on peeling up and replacing with porcelain tile.

To paint a better picture, as you walk in the bathroom the toilet is in the back right corner. To the right of the toilet is a small vanity. The doorway is on the left side as you walk in.

The issue, and why I’m hesitant to use self-leveling concrete, is the slope of the floor. From the wall behind the toilet to the wall across the toilet, the floor slopes ~2 inches downward. If I create a perimeter with 2x4s, there will be a noticeable lip of self-leveling concrete in the doorway going to the adjacent room (laundry room with just the poured floor exposed). I really don’t want to level the laundry room floor as well as this is a much larger area.

Fortunately, the legs on my washer and dryer can accommodate for this slope. I appreciate any tips/ideas on how to handle the lip of the self-leveling concrete. I don’t think a transition piece will work as the lip will thin out from left to right, but I may be wrong (rookie DIYer, first home). Worse case scenario, I use vinyl as another option, but I’d prefer to tile if possible.

Comment: Your "picture" leaves me dizzy. How can the doorway, which we're presumably walking through, be on our left? How can the vanity be to the right of the toilet which itself is on the right? (None of that may be crucial, but....)

Comment: The title you gave your post doesn't reflect what you actually asked, and the answer you selected doesn't address the question either. Good grief.

Comment: @isherwood I’ll make sure to include a CAD drawing and BOM next time. As you walk in the door and turn right, the toilet is on the left and the vanity is on the right. Both are to the right of the doorway as you walk in, but are oriented as stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tile it as it is; tile does not need to be level, ask any swimming pool. Smaller tile tolerates more deviations in the substrate than huge tile, when choosing tile.

If you find the slope upsetting, you could reduce it without trying to make it "perfectly flat" - indeed, my preference is to have it slope to a floor drain, but if you don't have and are not adding a floor drain a slight tendency to puddle in one area can still be useful for cleanup purposes when the floor gets wet.